# My CSS files are not responding for my Django Project. How am I suppose to make it work?

Tags: css, django, file, project

## base.html file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css 
    family=Tangerine:bold,bolditalic|Inconsolata:italic|Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static'css/blog.css'%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" 
     integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" 
     crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href=" https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static'css/zenburn.css' %}">

</head>
```

## Setting.py #

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

I have looked at all the solutions on the stack overflow. But none of them able to solve the issue  I have added {% load static %} on the base.html and also add the code on setting.py. I do not know what else I can do?

Comment: Have you tried hard refreshing the page (Ctrl F5?) / removing the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I don't know what causes it. But what I did was:

- Turned off my local server and restarted it.
- Then I went back to my page and did a hard refresh by pressing Ctrl+Shift+R
- If it didn't work the first time then I gave a hard refresh again and it worked that time.

I tried using hard refresh only but that doesn't work for some reason. You have to restart your server and turn it back on and hard refresh it. And it's not only for CSS it's for any static file. It just doesn't work for some reason and whenever I want to see the changes that I made I have to do all these steps.

But for some reason this problem does not occur in Firefox. So you can try opening your site on Firefox and see if it works.